# writing string as element attribute of xml file using embedded python in C

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, embed, lxml

I'm using etree from lxml to write a plain string as element attribute in xml file. the problem is when my string contains non english characters(non ascii), the program fails to write even with unicode conversion such as 
unicode(mystring, "utf-8")

here is an example

```
from lxml import etree as ET

doc = ET.parse('my_file.xml')
info = "préparation"
top = doc.getroot()
element1 = ET.Element("first_element")
element1.set("msg ",unicode(info,"utf-8")) 
top.append(element1)
file1= open('my_file.xml',"wb")
doc.write(file1)
file1.close()
```

this code doesn't give any errors but I can't get any result

content of 'my_file.xml'

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="parse.xsl" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article date="2017-04-27" langue="french" time="16:33:20"/>
```

I want to add 'element1' s a child of 'article' and add 'msg' as attribute of 'element1'.
edit : I'm sure that this issue is related to embedding python in C because this program works when I used a python code without embedding in C

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: thank you mzjn, I hope you can help me

Comment: i ran your exact code, with your exact file:
the only error was that you try to set `"msg "` attribute with space, after changing it to `"msg"` (without space) it worked like charm:
`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="parse.xsl" encoding="UTF-8"?><article date="2017-04-27" langue="french" time="16:33:20"><first_element msg="pr&#233;paration"/></article>`

Comment: thank you sepulchered, I had just deleted the space and still have the same problem. I forgot to mention that I'm using this piece of code within a python function called from C program.

Comment: It could be an encoding problem. To use UTF-8 as the encoding you would need this at the top of the Python source file: `#! coding: utf-8`. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/.

Comment: @mzjn That only declares the encoding of the source file, and is the default if the OP is using Python 3.  If using Python 2 OP would get a syntax error without a declared encoding due to use of non-ASCII.

Comment: @MarkTolonen: I got the "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file my_file.py on line 4, but no encoding declared" error when I tried to run the code without the `coding` pragma. I assumed that the OP uses
Python 2, since the `unicode` function does not exist in Python 3.

Comment: I'm sorry sepulchered you were right, I deleted the space and It worked from python code, but when I tried to embed this python code in C program it didn't work. now I'm sure that this issue is related to embedding python in C.can anyone help me please

Comment: already done mzjn, my python code begins with this line #! coding: utf-8 and still have the problem

Comment: Please show us how you embed Python in C and how the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: I have reported this problem in python bug tracker http://bugs.python.org/issue30195 would you take a look there, I provided two pieces of code(one of python and the other for C).thanks

Comment: I have solved the problem of writing non ascii characters to xml file, It's not related to embedding python in C, I just had to decode data as utf-8 before writing it instead of encoding it.